# Question history attributed changes to me that I didn't make

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, edits, revisions-list

I just made some minor edits to the text of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576023/algorithm-to-generate-1000-distinct-integers-in-the-range-0-8000).  I didn't edit the tags at all.  When I completed my edits, my edit showed as:

[image: Edit history]

Now, I *think* those tags were present before I started my edit, and so were probably slipped in by the OP in their edit grace window.  I have no problem with that tagging, but I don't like seeing edits attributed to me that I didn't make.  So, what the heck?

Comment: Your case just [got discovered](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100003/no-warning-when-op-edits-question-during-the-five-minute-grace-period) by moderator so there's good chance of them fixing it soon. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember there's a 5 minute grace period for edits if you own the revision.

The original author of the previous revision was making edits in the 5 minute grace period.

edit: I can't think of a way to disambiguate grace period owner edits slipped in between the time you clicked "edit" and "save". So this'll have to be a known issue.

Comment: Right, I understand what happened, but the net result was some edits being attributed to me that I didn't make.  Innocuous in this example, but you can certainly imagine circumstances where it's not, and even ways it could be gamed.  Seems like a serious oversight to me.

Comment: Changes in the 5 minute grace period still should be done to the original revision, not to the next one.