# No warning when OP edits question during the five minute grace period

Tags: bug, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question history attributed changes to me that I didn't make](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45478/question-history-attributed-changes-to-me-that-i-didnt-make)

When I was editing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841784/jquery-datatables-3x3-column-with-no-header) today the OP came back an made an edit during the grace period (five minutes?) when revisions are not tracked.

When I saved my edits I noticed that I'd apparently overwritten his update (he had added a link to the version of jQuery Data Tables he was using).

The system didn't warn me that changes had been made presumably because this is only tracked using revision numbers. Maybe it should do this (i.e. by calculating a hash of the original post then creating a new hash before allowing me to save. Then check if anything changed by comparing the hashes if the revision number is still the same - like a belt an braces check)?

Comment: The [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6841784/revisions) says that you edited *long* after the original poster's 5 minute grace period was up. About 25 minutes elapsed between the end of the grace period and the time that your edit was submitted. What am I missing here?

Comment: Yes...but the OP made **his** revisions during the grace period which the system didn't see or warn me about.

Comment: @Kev - did you have the edit screen open for 25+ minutes before saving?

Comment: @nick - um...possibly.

Comment: While this is focusing on a different aspect, the root "bug" is the same as has been [previously reported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45478/question-history-attributed-changes-to-me-that-i-didnt-make) and [previously discussed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73025/is-the-5-minute-window-responsible-for-making-me-look-bad). The report is marked "status-review", so there is hope for some things being changed.