# Editing a post that possibly has a suggested edit

Tags: support, edits

I'm fairly new, especially at editing posts, and I would like to help out a bit more.

I just edited a post, and when looking at the revision history, it shows I am the only editor.  However, the highlighted changed text does not match what I actually edited.

The post:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4821557/revisions

It's a short post, and the first time I entered the editor, I changed the final "System.ou" to "System.out".  The second time I entered the editor, I edited my change to also include changing "println(root)" to "println(string)".

However, it also shows I removed an extra append() function call, and I didn't touch that line.  If there was a pending suggested edit, does it just get rolled up in mine?  Did I miss some kind of notification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not part of the new suggested edits feature. Suggested edits actually lock the post from being edited until they are approved - rendering it impossible for this kind of merging. At least, that's how the system currently works.

---

Looking at the timestamps, it looks like you got [hosed by the 5 minute grace period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45478/question-history-attributed-changes-to-me-that-i-didnt-make). In essence, the answer was posted and you started an edit. But before you submitted the edit, the author managed to squeeze in an extra append() that wasn't there when you started the edit. So when you submit your edit of the version that doesn't have it, it looks like you removed the append() in the newer old version.

There is sometimes a banner that drops from the top to inform about simultaneous, but it is not always timely.

Comment: thanks for the clarification.  Is it best practice to just wait until five minutes have passed before editing a post?

Comment: @RD01 Usually, yes. It makes things easier for everyone, as this will prevent this type of cloaked scenario from happening to you again, and it also won't cut into the 5 minutes that authors typically get for minor fixes. Not required, but oft recommended.