# Simultaneous edits of different users merged as one?

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question history attributed changes to me that I didn't make](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45478/question-history-attributed-changes-to-me-that-i-didnt-make)

When editing a post, I noticed that after the edit another "correction" (which I hadn't made) seems to have been attributed to me. Let me explain:

I noticed that the OP of the following question misspelled "problem" as "probrem" just to get the title to pass: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309851/weird-probrem-model-proxy-view

I edited the title and removed the "people, help!" from the beginning of his question. Revision history can be viewed here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8309851/revisions

However, when I finalized my edit it seemed code had changed as well. And looking through the revision history, it seems as if I had been the one making that change. I didn't. This change, logically, caused Vladimir Jovic to rollback my edit.

Is this a bug on SO? Is it a feature? Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Comment: The deliberate misspelling of "Problem" is something I've seen before too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276901/vector-erase-iterator-out-of-range-in-c

Comment: @razlebe: [I guess that's because it's the stupidest, most pointless and annoying low-quality-filter in the entire world](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110789/remove-blacklist-filter-for-problem)... GRRR... /rant :P

Comment: @razlebe Oh yes, and that (the use of word filters and associated issues) has been discussed here on Meta at length. Not what my question is about though, should there be any confusion.

Comment: @Matt I'm starting to doubt its value having just performed a couple of quick searches for the string "Probrem" and "Ploblem"

Comment: @Bart Indeed, sorry if my comment is muddying the water. I'll go and find the right thread.

Comment: @razlebe http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/using-the-word-problem-in-titles for example.

Comment: Probably the OP (user336359) has edited the code in the five minutes grace period, and it was merged with your own edit.

Comment: @ShadowWizard That's what I'm assuming. Probably a difficult case to handle/correct (?), but especially in the case of code changes I see this as an issue. I would have made the same decision as Vladimir did and rolled back the edit.

Comment: To avoid such things, you can wait five minutes before clicking the "edit" button - it all boils down to the grace period "issue" as far as I can tell. (Edits made within five minutes of posting or previous edit are not logged at all and considered part of the original post or previous edit)

Comment: @ShadowWizard That seems to be a fair enough explanation and "work-around". Perhaps make it an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @GraceNote And of course there was a duplicate...didn't find it. Thanks and sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the OP (user336359) has edited the code in the five minutes grace period.

To avoid such problems, you can wait five minutes before clicking the "edit" button - it all boils down to the grace period "issue" as far as I can tell. (Edits made within five minutes of posting or previous edit are not logged at all and considered part of the original post or previous edit)