# Why is my edit not accurate?

Tags: bug, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question history attributed changes to me that I didn't make](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45478/question-history-attributed-changes-to-me-that-i-didnt-make)

I edited a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380262/whats-wrong-with-my-lambda-expression) earlier and somehow I replaced `List<Person>` with `GenericList<Person>` as can be seen here:

[image: Bad Edit]

I swear this **wasn't me**.

It said `GenericList<Person>` when I clicked **Edit**. I only removed 8 extra spaces causing indentation and clicked **Save**.

Looking at the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9380262/revisions) shows me changing it though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You started editing the the question when it was just *a few seconds old*. I wouldn't rule out a ninja edit by the OP replacing `GenericList<Person>` with `List<Person>` occurring *after* you started editing it.